# Does all http web Responses have content length field in the header ?

Tags: web-services, http, url, httpwebresponse, webresponse

Is there a standard, that says that all the http responses should have a Content-length field. Or is it URL specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not always there. Details at http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7230.html#header.content-length